# Difference between pre(html tag) and white-space:pre newline omission

Tags: html, css

I thought pre(html tag) active just like 'white-space:pre'. But it's not.

```
<pre>
aaa
bbb
</pre>

<p style="white-space:pre;">
aaa
bbb
</p>
```

`<pre>` ignore the first and last `\n`. But `<p>` keep the first `\n` and ignore the last one.
Why?

[jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/zmmbreeze/EkfYe/)

Comment: Related note: there is also at least one other implementation divergence: Firefox 30 does not copy newlines to the clipboard on `white-space:pre`, but does on `pre` elements. [Bugzilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116083). Modern Chrome does. Just because of that, I recommend sticking with `pre` elements.

Answer (score 8):

The HTML standard states:

> Note: In the HTML syntax, a leading newline character immediately
>   following the pre element start tag is stripped.

Read here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element

So, the `<pre>` element contains this special rule. It seems that if other types of elements have a `white-space:pre` setting, that rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Yeah. `<textarea>` and the obsolete element `<listing>` are the only other elements to drop leading newline characters during parsing.

Comment: Why does `<pre>` ignore the trailing newline?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That's because there are spaces after the last newline. See [this](https://jsbin.com/mapequpoba/edit?html,css,output), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492826/why-does-the-browser-not-render-a-line-break-caused-by-a-trailing-newline-charac).

Comment: @DecadeMoon I see. So, both a leading newline and a trailing newline is stripped. Maybe the HTML Standard needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they are the same. The reason you're getting the space on top for `<p>`s is because by default `<p>` adds an empty line above itself so that you can distinguish between paragraphs. `<pre>` doesn't do that, so you get no extra space there.

Comment: Although `<p>` normally has margins, it does not "insert a newline".

Comment: Nope, it's not the margin. That empty space is part of the paragraph's text-content. It's an empty line.

Comment: I change <p> to <div> and got same result. And I delete the first '\n' of <p>, the new line will disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/zmmbreeze/EkfYe/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `pre` element and the CSS setting `white-space: pre` are quite distinct constructs; it is a category error to confuse the two. But you seem to be referring to a difference in rendering as regards to line breaks.

[By the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.1), a line break immediately following a start tag shall be ignored, so

```
<pre>
aaa
bbb
</pre>
```

should be equivalent to

```
<pre>aaa
bbb
</pre>
```

and this should not change in any way if `p` is substituted for `pre` or some styling is added. But browsers don’t always play by the rules, and this is one of the cases.

They just treat elements differently. The morale is that you should avoid using the `pre` element as well as `white-space: pre`, and if you used them, stay tuned to this variation. When needed, do not follow the start tag immediately by a line break but a space and a line break (if you want to have an empty line at the start).

Comment: The rule you're referring to is a SGML rule. HTML is no longer an application of SGML, so that rule no longer applies. The most up-to-date HTML standard is the ["HTML Living Standard"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/). I recommend using it as the primary source.

Comment: “Living Standard” is an oxymoron; it’s making whatever Hixie thought this morning, or evening, the standard. But that’s irrelevant. The relevant thing is that browsers handle an end of line after a start tag in different ways in different contexts, and you should write your code so that it does not depend on such variation.

Answer (score -1):

The `<pre>`-Tag displays the content with a monospace font, wich means that every character has the same width.

It is easier to read instead of the standard-font of the browser, used in the `<p style="white-space:pre;">`.

Comment: Not addressing the question. He is wondering why there is an extra space above the content of a `<p style="white-space:pre">` and not on the `<pre>`

Comment: Even though this is not answering the exact question it is still a useful contribution the the difference between <pre> and white-space:pre, I think. It may be more appropriate as a comment though.