# Why does the browser not render a line break caused by a trailing newline character inside a "white-space: pre" element?

Tags: css, html

Both of these divs render the same. Why is the leading newline rendered but not the trailing newline (in the second div)? I read the [Line Breaking and Word Boundaries](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#line-breaking) section in the CSS3 spec but it doesn't explain this behavior.

```css
.pre {
  white-space: pre;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
hello
world</div>

<div class="pre">
hello
world
</div>
```

Comment: like br, if it stands last, it doesn't create an extra empty line . It only breaks it . If you want it to show, then add content behind it : `.pre:after {
  content:'';
}`

Comment: I think that both of these are same only. Position of end/closing tag doesn't matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does whitespace matter in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863588/when-does-whitespace-matter-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why? Well, to avoid compatibility problems, apparently.

The [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#whitespace) says:

> In order to avoid problems with SGML line break rules and inconsistencies among extant implementations, authors should not rely on user agents to render white space immediately after a start tag or immediately before an end tag.

[and also](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-break-transform):

> Note that the white space processing rules have already removed any tabs and spaces after the segment break before these checks [on the value of the white-space property] take place.

Now it is not clear exactly *which* inconsistencies would be introduced if the browsers were allowed to keep the whitespace before the end tag, but there you have it.

Comment: In the op example, there is a single white-space/break , which will not be rendered. if there is 2 line breaks , then one will be rendered and last still removed. W3C seems clear to me :)

Comment: Oh boy. Now it looks like they are actually _introducing_ inconsistencies! Not sure how to edit my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Because the last `\n` won't work. And the property `white-space: pre` works as it's called. It only adds newline before a word. The last `\n` is not recognized as a word.

Comment: ?? can you explain?  i do not see the connection with white-space:pre;

Comment: @GCyrillus I mean `white-space: pre` functions as it is called. It only works before the words you include in `<div></div>` and the last `\n` is not recognized as a word.