# How to preserve the last carriage return with pre-wrap?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the followwing use case in a React application but this is a pure CSS question:

- A text-area (`pre-wrap`) when `edited` state is `true`
- A div (`pre-wrap`) when `edited` state is `false`

Here are screenshots:
[image]

[image]

As you can see the last `\n` is ignored in the div.

How to take it into account and add a last empty line in the div?

I tried modifying `pre-wrap` to other values.

Comment: _"As you can see the last \n is ignored in the div."_  - actually we can't: you haven't shown us the raw text/bytes/etc of those elements' `#text` DOM nodes.

Comment: TL;DR: [HTML has a special-case rule to always ignore the last trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492826/why-does-the-browser-not-render-a-line-break-caused-by-a-trailing-newline-charac) (except in `<textarea>`). As a workaround, you could add an explicit `<br />` or another `[\r]\n` when you set the `.textContent` from JS - or fake it with `padding-bottom: `.